# Finetuning embeddings with torchtext - nn.Embedding vs. nn.Embedding.from_pretrained

Tags: pytorch, torchtext

I have been working with pretrained embeddings (Glove) and would like to allow these to be finetuned. I currently use embeddings like this:

```
word_embeddingsA = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_length)
word_embeddingsA.weight = nn.Parameter(TEXT.vocab.vectors, requires_grad=False)
```

Should I simply set requires_grad=True to allow the embeddings to be trained? Or should I do something like this

```
word_embeddingsA = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(TEXT.vocab.vectors, freeze=False)
```

Are these equivalent, and do I have a way to check that the embeddings are getting trained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are equivalent as states in [embedding](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#embedding):

> `freeze (boolean, optional)` – If `True`, the tensor does not get updated in the learning process. Equivalent to `embedding.weight.requires_grad = False`. Default: `True`

If `word_embeddingsA.requires_grad == True`, then embedding is getting trained, else it's not.